# How to prefetch image and save it locally on electron

Tags: javascript, image, vue.js, electron, offline

In my project, we have articles and with each article, the different image is associated. So, now we have to run our electron app offline and sync all the images to the user's system so that it can be served locally.
I'm currently using electron and VUE JS

Currently I have tried it with service worker:

**Register a service worker**

```
const path = require('path')

export function registerServiceWorker () {
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        console.log('inside')
        const workerPath = path.join(__dirname, 'sw_cache.js')
        console.log('workpath -> ', workerPath)
        window.addEventListener('load', () => {
            navigator.serviceWorker
                .register(workerPath)
                .then(reg => console.log('registered', reg))
                .catch(err => console.error('error registered worker', err))
        })
    }
}
```

**To cache all the images**

```
const CACHE_NAME = `cache-v1`
    
    const filesToCache = [
        'index.html',
        'as-nova.ttf'
    ];
    
    self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
        event.waitUntil(
            caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
            .then(function (cache) {
                return cache.addAll(filesToCache);
            })
            .catch(err => console.log('error: ' + err))
        );
    });
    
    self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
        console.log('fetching', event)
        event.respondWith(
            caches.match(event.request).then(cacheRes => {
                console.log('event: ' + event)
                console.log('event: ' + event.request)
                return cacheRes || fetch(event.request).then(fetchRes => {
                    return caches.open(dynamicCache).then(cache => {
                        cache.put(event.request.url, fetchRes.clone());
                        return fetchRes
                    })
                })
            })
        )
    })
    self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
        event.waitUntil(clients.claim());
    });
    self.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
        if (event.data && event.data.type === 'SKIP_WAITING') {
            self.skipWaiting()
        }
    })
```

Comment: I don't think you need Electron for this. You could simply use a Service Worker.

Comment: @customcommander Can you share an example because I was not able to make it work with the service worker? Where I'm supposed to register it? In main or renderer and what is the correct way?
I have added the code in question can you check?